# Cancel group by from query in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

How can I cancel the "group by" clause in my query in Laravel?

For example I have:

```
$myQuery = Table::select('column')->groupBy('column');
```

And then later in my code I want to remove the `group by` clause from

```
$myQuery = $myQuery->groupBy(null);
```

Comment: Why not just add it conditionally? What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @aynber I want to clone $myQuery and use it for another stuff but without the grouping...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with:

```php
$myQuery->groups = null;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can have 2 different variable to do it:

```
$base = Table::select('column');
withNoGroup= $base->get();
$withGroup = $base->groupby('column')->get();
```